# Getting a variable using $post ajax back from php to js response in WP

Tags: ajax

I have this in my JavaScript part:

```
$.post(
    WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
    {
        action : 'my_php_action_to_do',
    },
    function( response ) {
        alert( response.mycode );
    }
);
```

and this in my `my_php_action_to_do` php function:

```
function my_php_action_to_do() {

    $send_to_response['mycode'] = '1234';
    echo json_encode( $send_to_response );
    exit();

}
```

I can execute the php code in the php function and run the result post javascirpt code, but the problem I am facing is how to send the variable from the php function back to response and alert it or use in whatever way.

Now I am getting `undefined` in a popup window as a result.

How to do that in WordPress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the var through your ajax request:

```
$.post(
//be suer that this var is pointing to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
{
    action              : 'my_php_action_to_do',
    //here your var and its value
    my_var              : 'the_value'
},
function( response ) {
    response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    alert(response.message);
}
);
```

In your my_php_action_to_do function:

```
function my_php_action_to_do(){
    $var['message'] = $_POST['my_var'];
    //Send back the $var value in json format. You can send it in other format if you want
    echo json_encode( $var );
    exit();
}

//Don't forget to add your my_php_action_to_do function to wp_ajax_* action hook.

add_action('wp_ajax_my_php_action_to_do', 'my_php_action_to_do');
//or this if you want it to work in the frontend
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_php_action_to_do', 'my_php_action_to_do');
```

Comment: This part I know ;)

Comment: But I want to get the value of php variable back after the script in the function is done and send it back to javascript, so I can alert it in the response. how to do taht?

Comment: Hmm, I tried it and I get in alert `undefined`. Shoulc I use echo before json_encode?

Comment: No. Can you edit your question and post the full code you are trying?

Comment: `function( response ) {
            alert( response.mycode );
        }` in JS and in PHP I have this: `$send_to_response['mycode'] = '1234';
    echo json_encode( $send_to_response );` and I am gettign undefined in the popup ;(

Comment: With that piece of code saying that "it dosen't work" is not much. Please, post your full code, the erro can be anywhere. But do it by editing you question. Reading code in the comments can be difficult.

Comment: I tried to add `exit();` at the end, but it's the same. For some reason the variable is not send back to JS or something

Comment: Please, check my updated code in my question now.

Comment: Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Your updated code is not complete. For example, I can not see if the WPaAjax.ajaxurl var is defined or if you are registering your PHP funtion in the wordpress wp_ajax_* action hook. Also, you have missed the variable to send in your javascript. Please, read my answer again with more attetion.

Comment: I hove some database php code that is saving the data CORRECTLY in the database and I have registered my hook action in functions.php. That's not a problem.

Comment: But, thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: Read again my answer, the code, as I've posted, works.

Comment: You have probably error in the alert part. If I try `console.log(response);` instead of `alert ( response.mycode);` I am getting this in firebug `{"mycode":"1234"}` Any idea why the alert part in your code is not working?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not going to repeat myself. The code works as it is. If you modify it and stop working you have to post the changes you have made or nobody can help you.

Comment: What I am saying is that you cannot alert JSON in JavaScript. You need to make a string from it or something. Your code `alert(response.message);` is trying to do that, which is wrong. You need to convert it before alert. I am getting the JSON back to my JS as resonse, which is good. The problem is that how to alert json.

Comment: Ohhh yes, of course but I'm alert response.message which is correct, the json object is response.

Comment: When I try this `alert(JSON.stringify(response));` I will get this in a popup: `"{\"mycode\":\"1234\"}0"` but when I will try this: `alert(JSON.stringify(response.mycode));` I am getting `undefined`. Why is that?

Comment: read my code carefully. See how I use `jQuery.parseJSON()` function. Also, if you don't use jQuery, you can use `JSON.parse()` which is supported by almost every browser.

Comment: Thanks, the parsing part that you added in the last update helps. Now, it's working ;)